# Simplest way to evaluate $\int\frac{\tan(\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}))}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$ other than my method

Tags: integration

I want to integrate this-

> $$\int\frac{\tan(\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}))}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$

Now,I have found a way to do this by substituting $u=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$ and then doing it by substitution as $\displaystyle du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$ and then solving $\displaystyle\int\tan u\space du$.

But, I want to know if there is any other way to solve this problem other than my method.

Please consider posting an answer only if the method is different from my approach.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Did you try the substitution $x=\sinh (u) $

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima No...I didn't...

Comment: the solution is given by $$-\log \left(\cos \left(\log \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yeah...I used $\sec$ instead of $\cos$ and got rid of the $-$ sign...;-)

Comment: Your way is pretty much the best way I guess.

Answer (score 6):

**hint**

Put $x=\sinh (u)=\frac {e^u-e^{-u}}{2} $,

$$dx=\cosh (u)du $$
$$1+x^2=\cosh^2 (u) $$
$$x+\sqrt {1+x^2}=e^u $$

it becomes $$\int \tan (u)du=\ln (\frac {1}{|\cos (u)|})+C $$
with
$$e^u-e^{-u}=2x $$
$$e^{2u}-2xe^u-1=0$$

$$u=\ln (x+\sqrt {1+x^2})$$

Comment: (+1)Nice method...lets see what other methods come up in the upcoming answers...;-)

Comment: @tatan The substitution Salahamam_Fatima suggests *is* essentially the one you used: the function $x \mapsto \ln (x + \sqrt{1 + x^2})$ is nothing other than the "inverse" hyperbolic sine, $\textrm{arsinh} = \sinh \!\vert_{[0, \infty)}^{-1}$. The only difference is that this method uses "reverse substitution"---in this case this method is somewhat cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: @Travis Yeah...it prevents things from messing up as in my method...that's why I liked it...;-)

Comment: Btw how do we pronounce $\cosh x$?Is it *cosh* or is it *cos-h*?

Comment: @tatan It is hyperbolic cosine.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Yeah I know its that...but when we read it out do we say $\cosh x$ as *Hyperbolic cosine of x*?

Comment: @tatan Your method looks okay to me. In any case, I usually hear (and say) <kɑʃ>.

Comment: @Travis Thanks...This MIT lec (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=er_tQOBgo-I) also uses *hyperbolic cosine* and *cosh* interchangebly...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is setup to test your formulae probably. If you know that $\int \frac {1}{\sqrt {a^2+x^2}}=ln|x+\sqrt {a^2+x^2}|$ then you know whats the plan to solve it.